# How many .ToString("N0") can I have?

Tags: vb.net

I am getting a warning:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning BC42322 Runtime errors might occur when converting 'String' to 'IFormatProvider'.

I have 2 `.ToString("N0")` in my code in the same Sub. Can I not have 2 in the same sub? They go to different labels but, I am new to VB as well so please do not judge. Thanks!

```
If Integer.TryParse(input, infantry) Then
    Dim hpai = Integer.Parse(frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text = (hpai - infantry * 2).ToString("N0")

    frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text -= input.ToString("N0") '<---- One that gets the warning

Else
    ' handle not an int inputted case
End If
```

Comment: What makes you think that error is due to how many times you use the method?

Comment: Please [edit] to include the relevant portions of your code. There are no limitations on the number of ToString calls you can make in a procedure, but that's not what the error says anyway. Read the words in the error message - they tell you **exactly** what the problem is with your code. The words are not there just to occupy space on the screen; they're giving you specific information. You just have to actually read them.

Comment: @Plutonix because, well I do not know. The first one works, the second one really doesn't. Here is the code, will be in the edit.

Comment: You cannot perform math on strings.  Turn on Option Strict and that will not even compile.  Do the math, then convert to string for the display.  Better yet use variables to store the values and do the math and use controls to simply show the user what you need to show them.

Comment: @Plutonix The reason it is in that form is because I have values that go into the millions and I wanted to keep the comma form in tact. What do you mean Option Strict?

Comment: Make the very first line of your code to be this: `Option Strict On`

Comment: @Verdolino Of the If Statement or?

Comment: @CaptainCaboose Of the file.

Comment: @Verdolino Same error occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It won't fix the error, it helps you see errors before they happen so to speak. What are you trying to do with this "N0" format anyway? See if my answer helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this line:

```
frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text -= input.ToString("N0")
```

You're applying the `-=` operator to **STRINGS**. This operator has no meaning for strings. Are you trying to apply some kind of reverse-concatenation? Removing any occurrence of `input` from within the label text? That code just doesn't make sense at all.

If you're actually trying to do a numeric operation, you need to actually work with **numbers**... convert the label string to an integer, not the integer to a string.

```
If Integer.TryParse(input, infantry) Then

    Dim hpai = Integer.Parse(frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text = (hpai - infantry * 2).ToString("N0")

    Dim numPlayer = Integer.Parse(frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text)

    frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text = (numplayer - input).ToString("N0") '<---- One that gets the warning

Else
    ' handle not an int inputted case
End If
```